# How to handle several user requests in pytelegrambotapi[Telegram]

Tags: bots, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I am new to telegram bot development. I use python 3.9
My bot works fine when 1 person uses but 2 or more it gives me `Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: message to edit not found`
I use pytelegrambotapi and imported telebot
Here is my code:

```
import telebot
@bot.message_handler(commands = ["start"])
def start_bot(message):
    global user
    #--------creating new user or load old user data--------
    user = USER(message.chat.id)
    #-----------asking-----------
    if user.isFull():
        user.last_message = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 
                                             f"Hello {user.fish}", 
                                             reply_markup=MAIN_MENU)
    else:
        bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "*Some post", reply_markup=None)
        user.info_post_id = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, user.user_info_checking()).message_id
        user.last_message = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Name:')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_name_and_age(message):
    global user
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    if user.last_message.text=='Name:':
        user.fish = message.text
        bot.delete_message(chat_id, message.message_id)
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=chat_id,
                                message_id=user.info_post_id,
                                text=user.user_info_checking(),
                                reply_markup=None)
        user.last_message = bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=chat_id,
                                                    message_id=user.last_message.message_id,
                                                    text="Age:",
                                                    reply_markup=None)
```

[got this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7vxX.png)

I need to keep my bot chat clean so I need to delete or edit messages but I got the error.
I used user class to save induvidual message and its id to track but still failed:

```
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
        self.motion = None
        self.info_post_id = None
        self.last_message = None
        self.last_error = None
        self.post_counter = None
        self.current_post = None
        self.current_post_id = 0
        self.current_post_link = None
        self.current_catalog = None
        self.current_channel_id = None
        self.current_category = None
        self.current_sub_category = None
```

Comment: I used 

`users={}
@bot.message_handler(commands = ["start"])
def start_bot(message):
    global users
    chat_id = str(message.chat.id)
    print('bot started', chat_id)
    bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
    users[chat_id] = USER(chat_id)`
but my friend says if 1000 or more users use this bot and you write it in the object it is bad. What I should do then? And I do not know about webhook and polling it is a commercial bot it should take many requests. Any idea or tutorials to build a strong bot?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely the use of your global variable `user`. When two different users are using your bot at the same time, you write data from both of them into this object. Instead you do something like

```
user_info = defaultdict(USER)

...

def start_bot(message):
    global user_info 
    #--------creating new user or load old user data--------
    user = user_info[message.from_user.id]
    ...
```

Note that I used `message.from_user.id` rather then `message.chat.id` because for messages net in groups chats, `message.chat` will be the group chat, while `message.from_user` will be information about the user who sent the message.

It may be that pyTelegramBotAPI has some built-in mechanism for storing user-related data, but I'm not very familiar with that library …

Comment: writing it to python object takes a lot I think so says, my friend. Any other options I can use? I am in the corner. The deadline is coming. I am a junior with no knowledge.

Comment: I don't understand what the question is here